# My setColor methods are getting mixed up?

Tags: java, multithreading, colors, sleep

Okay I posted a question a while back regarding how to get a method to pause without pausing the whole program. Here's the link for context- [How do I make method pause without pausing the whole program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366777/how-do-i-make-method-pause-without-pausing-the-whole-program). The answer I got was to create a new thread and pause it from there.
The new thread worked, but now I have a different problem. Since I'm running flip 5-6 times simultaneously the three setcolor methods, which all use the same Graphics, are getting mixed up. I think it's because some threads are setting the color to green, some to black and some to white. The result is that the pieces rapidly change color during their animation. How do I fix this?

```
  public void flip(int row, int col, Graphics window)
{
Color a;
    Color b = new Color(0, 100, 0);
if (pieces[row][col]==2)
    a = Color.black;
else
    a = Color.white;
for ( int size = 90; size>=0; size-=2)
{
    try { Thread.sleep(5,5555); } catch (InterruptedException exc){}
    window.setColor(b);
    window.fillRect(row*100+3, col*100+3, 94, 94);
    window.setColor(a);
    window.fillOval(row*100 + 5, col*100+5+(90-size)/2, 90, size);

}
if (a==Color.black)
    a=Color.white;
else
    a=Color.black;
for ( int size = 0; size<=90; size+=2)
{
    try { Thread.sleep(5,5555); } catch (InterruptedException exc){}
    window.setColor(b);
    window.fillRect(row*100+3, col*100+3, 94, 94);
    window.setColor(a);
    window.fillOval(row*100 + 5, col*100+5+(90-size)/2, 90, size);
}
}
```

Comment: Code? (`catch (CommentTooShortException e) {}`)

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are now using Threads which all change the same value, you need to learn about synchronization.